# Self attention: Function VS Class Implementation:

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I implemented self attention in tensorflow keras initially with just one function and then later with the help of Class.I implemented the method in two distinct ways ( 1: Function and 2: Class). Let me to present both approaches first, and then I will describe the problem:

> **What is my task:**

My goal is to process TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 6, 64) (8 time stamps one by one (6 * 64)) through self attention and get self attention feature map for every time stamp and then concatenate it again into output tensor shape (None, 8, 6, 64)

> **First Implementation with the help of Function:**

```
def conv1d(x, channels, ks=1, strides=1, padding='same'):
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, ks, strides, padding, activation='relu', use_bias=False,
                                  kernel_initializer='HeNormal')(x)
    return conv


# Self attention
def my_self_attention(x, channels):
    size = x.shape
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[2], x.shape[3]])
    f = conv1d(x, channels)
    g = conv1d(x, channels)
    h = conv1d(x, channels)
    attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(
        tf.matmul(g, Permute((2, 1))(f)))  # query multiply with key and then softmax on it
    sensor_att_fm = tf.matmul(attention_weights, h)
    gamma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("gamma", [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    o = gamma * sensor_att_fm + x
    # return tf.reshape(o, shape = [-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])
    return tf.reshape(o, shape = [-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])

refined_fm = tf.concat([my_self_attention(tf.expand_dims(my_input[:, t, :, :], 1), 64) for t in range(my_input.shape[1])], 1)
```

**

> **2nd Implementation with the help of Class**

```
def conv1d(channels, ks=1, strides=1, padding='same'):
        conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, ks, strides, padding, activation='relu', use_bias=False,
                                      kernel_initializer='HeNormal')
        return conv
    
    
    class my_self_attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
        def __init__(self, channels):
            super(my_self_attention, self).__init__()
            self.query = conv1d(channels)
            self.key = conv1d(channels)
            self.value = conv1d(channels)
            self.gamma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("gamma", [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    
        def call(self, x):
            x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[2], x.shape[3]])
            f = self.query(x)
            g = self.key(x)
            h = self.value(x)
            attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(
                tf.matmul(g, Permute((2, 1))(f)))  # query multiply with key and then softmax on it
            sensor_att_fm = tf.matmul(attention_weights, h)
            o = self.gamma * sensor_att_fm + x
            # return tf.reshape(o, shape = [-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])
            return tf.reshape(o, shape=[-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])
      
    
sa = my_self_attention(channels)
refined_fm = tf.concat([sa(tf.expand_dims(my_input[:, t, :, :], 1)) for t in   range(my_input.shape[1])], 1)
```

> **Problem**

From my perspective, I implemented the same method in 2 separate ways. The model's performance should be similar. However, model performance dropped by over 3% over class implementation. I'm not sure why. Could someone please respond?

Comment: Define your attention layer once like you are doing in the second option: `sa = my_self_attention(channels)`

Comment: I did not get your point completely. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I am just pointing out the difference.

Comment: @ it means everything is same. Then why performance of model is different?

Answer (score 1):

The first method is has way more operations, layers, and trainable weights, since `my_self_attention` is called in the loop for every timestep. Check out the `model.summary()` and you will quickly see the differences:

First model with way more parameters:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Permute

def conv1d(x, channels, ks=1, strides=1, padding='same'):
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, ks, strides, padding, activation='relu', use_bias=False,
                                  kernel_initializer='HeNormal')(x)
    return conv

def my_self_attention(x, channels):
    size = x.shape
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[2], x.shape[3]])
    f = conv1d(x, channels)
    g = conv1d(x, channels)
    h = conv1d(x, channels)
    attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(
        tf.matmul(g, Permute((2, 1))(f)))  # query multiply with key and then softmax on it
    sensor_att_fm = tf.matmul(attention_weights, h)
    gamma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("gamma", [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    o = gamma * sensor_att_fm + x
    # return tf.reshape(o, shape = [-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])
    return tf.reshape(o, shape = [-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((8, 6, 64))
outputs = tf.concat([my_self_attention(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:, t, :, :], 1), 64) for t in range(inputs.shape[1])], 1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model.summary())
```

```
....
Total params: 98,304
Trainable params: 98,304
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Second model with fewer parameters:

```
def conv1d(channels, ks=1, strides=1, padding='same'):
  conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, ks, strides, padding, activation='relu', use_bias=False,
                                kernel_initializer='HeNormal')
  return conv

class my_self_attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, channels):
      super(my_self_attention, self).__init__()
      self.query = conv1d(channels)
      self.key = conv1d(channels)
      self.value = conv1d(channels)
      self.gamma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("gamma", [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

  def call(self, x):
      x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[2], x.shape[3]])
      f = self.query(x)
      g = self.key(x)
      h = self.value(x)

      attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(
          tf.matmul(g, Permute((2, 1))(f)))  # query multiply with key and then softmax on it
      sensor_att_fm = tf.matmul(attention_weights, h)
      o = self.gamma * sensor_att_fm + x
      return tf.reshape(o, shape=[-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((8, 6, 64))
sa = my_self_attention(64)
outputs = tf.concat([sa(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:, t, :, :], 1)) for t in   range(inputs.shape[1])], 1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model.summary())
```

```
...
Total params: 12,289
Trainable params: 12,289
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Together, oh Okay, got it. But see my **task**, which one is achieving my task. So I should keep that!

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: My goal is to process TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 6, 64) (8 time stamps one by one (6 * 64)) through self attention and get self attention feature map for every time stamp and then concatenate it again into output tensor shape (None, 8, 6, 64). So which way of implementation is achieving this?

Comment: Yes but I also mentioned that both work same?

Comment: Yes, the inputs and outputs are the same.